What kind of range hood do I need?
I just moved into a relatively old house and removed the old stove and range hood, which were both nonfunctional. The hood when removed revealed one broken wire coming out of the cabinets (and not obviously accessible through the cabinets). There is a fan vent to the top right of the stove area but the hood was not otherwise directly venting to the outside. Can anyone advise what kind of range hood it makes sense to get for this situation? Is it possible to hard wire to these existing wires (and would I need an electrician’s help) or do I need one with a power cord? Is this fan thing enough ventilation for a gas range with an under-cabinet hood?




As long as you're replacing your stove, I'd highly consider going with an induction stove. Rewiring America has a great guide covering costs, available rebates, and the risks of gas stoves. A recent RMI study found that "nearly 13 percent of childhood asthma cases in the United States are associated with gas stove usage — a risk similar to secondhand smoke."

The hood size is driven by the range size, based on the instruction manual coming with the range. The hood most often must be the same width as the range or wider. It is usual to have the hood same width as the range.
The manual will also dictate how high above the range the hood must be. Just by eyeballing your picture, it appears you'd have room for the standard no-frills within-room-airflow under-cabinet hoods in the "cheap" aisle at the local bog-box store.
Gas ranges do not need chimneys, as long as the house isn't sealed up tight like one of those geo-experiment habitats space agencies use to test for Mars missions. Based on the ventilation fan in the upper right corner, your house is rather older and probably leaks like a sieve ventilation-wise, so running a gas range in it should not be a problem, unless you have recently super-insulated your home. You can try cleaning and lubricating or replacing the ventilation fan, which would help move some air through the kitchen, if you're worried about gas combustion effects. Note that if the gas flame is all blue, then the gas is burning completely. But a Carbon Monoxide detector in the room would be a good choice, too, just to be sure.
The wire is not usable to power the hood. It is lamp wire, which should never be buried in the wall or cabinet. You should have the lamp wire followed back to the junction where it attaches to the house wiring and exterminate the lamp wire with extreme prejudice. You may have to take the upper cabinet off the wall to do this: it should have screws to the back wall and to the side cabinet. Then replace the lamp wire with a proper code-compliant cable that your local authority would be happy with. Note that if you are in an apartment with neighbors behind the next wall, your local authority may require the landlord to hire an electrician to do this work.

Downvoter, what's the problem?

Thank you so much, this is a very helpful answer! I will definitely look into getting that lamp wire removed, cleaning out the vent, and I'll get a range hood with its own power cable.

@CalvinRunnels Your average range hood probably won't come with a power cable. They'll be expected to be powered from behind the wall or above through the upper cabinet via a separately-supplied piece of Romex (NM-B) or armored cable.

@Triplefault it really depends.  The cheapo range hoods generally require hardwiringl the midrange and up often have a plug-in cord.  Obviously, the OP would be on the hook to provide electrical power either way, whether hardwired or plug-in—that lamp cord has to be connected to something.

The best solution would be to give up enough space in the upper cabinet to allow a vented range hood to connect to the hole the fan is in now. Basically cutting a big enough hole in the top and bottom of the cabinet to allow the duct to pass through it. That's a far better solution than an unvented or "recirculating" hood and a separate fan in the wall, though at least there is the separate fan in the wall, unlike a lot of places with a recirculating/unvented hood installed.
As already correctly answered, that cord is totally unacceptable, however awkward it may be to follow and remove, it needs to be removed. At which point you can replace it with a suitable cable, and provide a junction box or a receptacle to suit whatever range hood you choose.

Thank you! Would you mind explaining why the lamp cord is so unacceptable?  Is it how it's exposed at the end, or something else?

Lamp cord is not made to be hidden away in walls for decades. Both the design and the type of insulation are not suitable for the use, and there is a significant chance of it failing and causing a fire.
